# Activity on SensorEventListener

Tags: java, android

I want an activity on the light sensor but the resume method shows error.

```
package com.example.user.projectandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class pushup extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;
EditText ed;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("myn", "onCreate: ");
    setContentView(R.layout.ushup);

     ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    SensorManager sensorManager=
(SensorManager)getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("myn", "onpause: ");
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();                                                       
sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensor, 
                         SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);//error                      
  }
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Log.d("myn", "onSensorChanged: ");
if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
ed.setText(""+sensorEvent.values[0]);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}
}
```

Error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.hardware.SensorManager.registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: How do you know that the `resume method` yields error?

Comment: And do attach logcat

Comment: I just edit, sry for previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, As I can see the problem is that you have declared `SensorManager's` object two times which is hence leading to a `NullPointerException`. Try removing the `SensorManager` from the line described below and correct this as:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Hope it helps...